# GPS Status and TurnOnOff

Tags: android, gps, toggle

I'd like a togglebutton changing status of GPS and a TextView with
the current status of GPS.

But When I implemets LocationListener and unimplemente methods like:

```
package com.wissen.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Hello extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My Eclipse compile it but the android divice get :Application stopped unexpectedly...

I thinks that's realy easy could anyone help me?
Thank You

Comment: Use Eclipse's logcat view to see the stacktrace and exception being thrown on the device. You'll probably be thankful in the future unless you intend to shoot in the dark whenever your apps "Unexpectedly stop".

Answer (score 3):

you need to call `super.onCreate()` when overriding the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

You need to set GPS Permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file, as follows,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```